# How can I implement an application like Prezi.com flash prezentation editor?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, css, html5-animation

I really like the zooming process in Prezi.com flashs app.

I didn't find any documentation on how to implement the prezi app.

Maybe some of you knows how to design or implement the final zoom by trajectory in application.

Finally I want to use that in a website to create a more interactive content prezentation of the company website to the user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

zooming process is a number of parallel motion tweens for `x`, `y` and (imho) a custom parameter `scale` of the presentation, which itself seems to be a kind of resource holder that hides or shows content according to `x`, `y` and `scale` values